# wp custom menu creation with sub menu/mega menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am trying to create a custom WordPress menu with bootstrap classes, with submenu( in product option) the code I written was given below

```
<?php 
        $menu_name = 'main-menu'; //menu slug or menu location
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_name );
    $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
    ?>
    <pre>
    <?php print_r($menuitems); ?></pre>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
    <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
    </button>
    <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
    <ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0'>
    <?php
      $count = 0;
        $submenu = false;
        foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
            // set up title and url
            $title = $item->title;
            $link = $item->url;
    
            // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
            if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
    
            // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
            $parent_id = $item->ID;
        ?>
          <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link " href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
               <?php endif; ?>
              <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>
                <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="<?php echo $link; ?>" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <?php endif; ?>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
              <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
              </ul>
        </li>
            <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
    
        <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
         </li>
              <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>
    
    <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

this is my code to generate a menu with a submenu in WordPress but the result I get is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN9S8.png)

I want the dropdown in products... Can anyone help

Comment: You need to look at the nav_walker not the template

Comment: can you give some references on this?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/